# Do I need to call done() at the end of a promise chain if I have catch()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native's docs says:

> Note that we call done() at the end of the promise chain - always make sure to call done() or any errors thrown will get swallowed.

Is it nessary when I have a catch block at the end?

```
dataLayer.enter() {
 .then((responseData) => {

      console.log('enter responseData ->', responseData);

 })  
 .catch(function(error) {

    console.log('enter error ->', error)

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `catch` block doesn't have a problem, then it isn't necessary to add a `done()` to the end of the chain. In the example you provided, it should be fine. However, if the `catch` did something like attempt to output the value of `this.state.foo` then an error would be generated that might get swallowed up. (The reason `this.state.foo` wouldn't work in my example of a potential problem is that the `catch` function you have is not bound to `this` context and would result in an error.) Adding a `.done()` at the end of a promise chain is good form and a little extra insurance.

Suggested code update:

```
dataLayer.enter() {
  .then((responseData) => {

    console.log('enter responseData ->', responseData);

  })  
  .catch(error => {

    console.log('enter error ->', error)

  })
  .done();
```